# What is the word or phrase that exclusively indicates "..", the "go to parent directory" argument for directory navigation operations?

Tags: directory, path, operating-system, filesystems, semantics

When working with filesystems, on most operating systems, and programs running on those operating systems, `..` is taken to mean "the relative parent directory."

So for example

```
cd ..
```

means "change directory from my current directory, to the parent of my current directory."

```
ls ~/../test
```

means "list files and directories in the `test` directory, which is in the parent directory of my `~` directory.

```
cat /home/me/documents/../test.txt
```

means "print to terminal the text of the `test.txt` document, which is in the `/home/me` directory (the parent of `/home/me/documents`)

I would like to know the word or phrase that, when I say it or write it, a relatively domain-knowledgeable person will know that I am saying/speaking of this concept of `..`. I'm no linguist but I believe what I'm seeking is inclusivity (word and concept are intermingled) and exclusivity (the word generally means the single concept alone).

"Relative parent directory" doesn't work. That phrase refers to any file or folder's relative parent directory.

"Navigate to parent directory" doesn't work. That phrase refers to the action of navigating to a parent directory (which can be achieved in many ways).

"Argument one passes to most programs on most operating systems to indicate the program should navigate to the parent directory in the given path" is too long. Surely the concept can be shortened?

I have tried googling this. As one can imagine, it is nearly impossible to google this question. Documents like [Redhat's documentation on navigating using cd](http://archive.download.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/7.3/fr/doc/RH-DOCS/rhl-gsg-en-7.3/s1-navigating-cd.html) simply refer to `..` as `..`.

> The command cd .. tells your system to go up to the directory
>   immediately above the one in which you are currently working. cd ../..
>   tells it to go up two directories.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)) also refers to it simply as `..`

> cd .. will move you up one directory. So, if you are /usr/bin/tmp, cd
>   .. moves you to /usr/bin, while cd ../.. moves you to /usr (i.e. up
>   two levels). You can use this indirection to access subdirectories
>   too. So, from /usr/bin/tmp, you can use cd ../../local to go to
>   /usr/local.

The [Linux Information Project](http://www.linfo.org/dot.html) refers to it as "dot dot." This feels weird but so far seems the only solution.

**What is the word that means `..`?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question - more likely a linguistics question https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I respect your opinion, but I disagree, for three reasons. 1. I believe this is a "programming conventions / semantics" question that could be described another way as "what does the .. argument do when I give it to cd?" or, similar to something like "what does 'var' mean in Javascript"? 2. I think programmers are far more likely to have the answer to this question than linguists. 3. Programmers define terms for their domain regularly, and this is not typically referred to as "linguistics" but assumed to be an aspect of programming.

Comment: I will politely agree to disagree with you.  While I agree with you on the type of question is 'computer-lingo' related, I still think this is not a programming question and should not be in here. Also, programmers are not only on SO, they are also on other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I understand. I'll repost there without complaint if the community decides alongside you that the question doesn't belong here, until then I will leave as-is and let the community decide.

Comment: Fair enough.  Curious: what's issue with saying `..` represents the parent directory from the current location/position/directory?

Comment: It's a bit lengthy. I'm righting a virtual filesystem and need functions that handle "." and "..". Naming them "handleDot" and "handleDotDot" feels... weird

Comment: I'm not sure about a standard name, but would currentDir and parentDir not work for you? Interesting question though

Comment: Unfortunately no, currentDir means "Current Directory," and refers to a directory, not the concept of "." which is the argument presented in paths to refer to "current directory." Same for parentDir.